# Converting .txt to excel format

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .txt format which  is the below format .Tried the below code, however for each space getting unanamed columns as header and giving incorrect output

```
Data : .txt format 

ID     FULL NAME                  SECURITY NUMBER
1234   ALEXANDER XAVIER ROBEN    A.B. HAPPY123 
3456   MOHAMMED ALI ZAFAR        B.8 GHDF67
```

Tried Code :

```
# Read the .txt file with space-separated headers
df = pd.read_csv('input.txt', delimiter=' ')

# Concatenate each header into a single word with hyphens
df.columns = ['-'.join(header.split()) for header in df.columns]

# Save the modified DataFrame back to a .txt file
df.to_csv('output.txt', sep=' ', index=False)


# Reading the .txt format and converting into excel format

excel = 'ConsRelLab19072023 (1).txt'
df = pd.read_csv(excel, sep=' ')
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Incorrect Output :

```
 ID   Unanamed1   Unanamed2 Unanamed3 FULL     NAME   Unanamed4  Unnamed5  SECURITY   NUMBER
1234  ALEXANDER   XAVIER     ROBEN                    A.B.HAPPY   123 
3456  MOHAMMED    ALI        ZAFAR                    B.8         GHDF67
```

Actual output required is .xlsx format:

```
ID     FULL NAME                 SECURITY NUMBER
1234   ALEXANDER XAVIER ROBEN    A.B.HAPPY123 
3456   MOHAMMED ALI ZAFAR        B.8 GHDF67
```

Appreciate help, thanks

Comment: pass `delimiter='\s\s+'` or `delimiter='\s{2,}'` to `read_csv`.

Comment: Is this a [fixed-width](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) file?

Comment: There's some confusion here. This text file doesn't contain Comma Separated Values. That sample looks like fixed-width data. Use `read_fwd` instead. An Excel (xlsx) file isn't a text file at all, it's a ZIP package containing XML files.

Comment: It isnt fixed width file. Thank you , using read_fwd worked partially .But need to format at the   time of export as few columns still are getting split , so as the values under it .

Comment: The data you posted is fixed width. Do you have any other data with different sizes? Post a representative sample

Answer (score 1):

`CSV` stands for Comma Separated Values. That file isn't separated by a single character, much less commas. Columns seem to have a fixed width. To load such files use [read_fwf](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html). The function will try to infer the column sizes by inspecting the first 100 lines.

```
df = pd.read_fwf('input.txt')
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

An Excel (xlsx) file isn't a text file at all. It's a ZIP package contained well-defined XML documents. Each cell value is stored as a separate element so there's no "format" involved.

If `read_fwf` can't determine the columns you can specify them explicitly through the `colspecs` parameter, a list of `from,to` tuples

The question's example works without having to specify the columns:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

text="""ID     FULL NAME                  SECURITY NUMBER
1234   ALEXANDER XAVIER ROBEN    A.B. HAPPY123 
3456   MOHAMMED ALI ZAFAR        B.8 GHDF67
"""

df=pd.read_fwf(StringIO(text))
```

The types are :

```
>>> df.dtypes
ID                  int64
FULL NAME          object
SECURITY NUMBER    object
dtype: object
```

The contents

```
>>> df
     ID               FULL NAME SECURITY NUMBER
0  1234  ALEXANDER XAVIER ROBEN   A.B. HAPPY123
1  3456      MOHAMMED ALI ZAFAR      B.8 GHDF67
```

The text values don't contain any leading space:

```
>>> df.loc[1,'FULL NAME']
'MOHAMMED ALI ZAFAR'
>>> df.loc[1,'SECURITY NUMBER'] 
'B.8 GHDF67'
```

Comment: It isnt fixed column width so putting colspecs  doesnt work since for some columns such name will not have fixed width and doesnt work  as expected

Comment: What you posted *is* fixed width. Even `SECURITY NUMBER` which seems to be off by 1 character in the title has a fixed width. If the file contains more data that doesn't align properly, post it in the question

Comment: when we say fixed width , the fixed width belongs to the values  in the column right. For eg. under security number the fixed width to be considered based on the values under security number .But if we see that the security number values /full name col values will not have fixed width

Comment: @technical did you actually try this? Because just `read_fwf()` with the text you provided works fine and returns 3 columns with 2 rows, without any leading space

Answer (score 0):

I have no Excel Modul installed, but you can open csv in Excel to: [Read text to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html)

```
import pandas as pd

cols = ['ID','FULL NAME','SECURITY NUMBER']
df = pd.read_fwf('df.txt', header=1, names= cols, colspecs=[(0, 5), (9, 31), (32, 40)])
print(df)

df.to_csv('outfile.csv', sep=';', index=False)

#df1 = pd.read_csv('outfile.csv', sep=';')
#print(df1)
```

Output:

```
     ID             FULL NAME SECURITY NUMBER
0  1234  EXANDER XAVIER ROBEN         A.B. HA
1  3456      HAMMED ALI ZAFAR         B.8 GHD
```